# Is the following possible?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am confused about a simple question:

Is $X\sim N(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})$ possible?

My answer is no, because of the $Var[X] = E[X^2]-m_x^2$
If it is true, then $E[X^2]=0.5$, which is impossible.

Is it true? Could anyone explain it more clearly?

Thanks! Hope to ask further:

Given $X = x$, $Y$ has a geometric distribution with parameter $x$, and $X\sim N(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})$. Is this possible? The answer is negative; however I have no idea about it.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, normal mean $0.5$, variance $0.25$ is just fine. Note the minus sign.

Comment: Something is wrong with your arithmetic.  If $X$ has mean $1/2$ and variance $1/4$, then $E[X^2]$ will be $1/2$, not 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the (correct) formula $\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-\mu_X^2$ that you gave, we get $E(X^2)=\frac{1}{4}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}$, which is no problem.

The variance puts no constraint whatsoever on the mean.